# Having trouble using razor C# with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

I am trying to get Razor (C#) and javascript to play nicely together but I can't seem to do it.  I have searched the other articles on StackOverflow, but none of them seem 
to work for me.

### Some noticeable differences from other posts and mine include the following:

I am using an external JavaScript file (not mandatory, but it is there).

I am using a cshtml file for the header layout for all pages (which puts the head tag in a different file than the one actually attempting to call the function.

### I also use jQuery, if it would be easier that way.

### What I am trying to accomplish:

### All I need to do is get the contents of a tag (innerHTML, or .html in jQuery) (by id, class, whatever) and assign that value to "AppState["gEntryID"] for use with the next page.

### Some things I have tried:

```
function entryClickHandler()
{
    @AppState["gEntryID"] = document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML;
}
```

AND

```
function entryClickHandler()
{
    <text>
    @AppState["gEntryID"] = document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML;
    </text>
}
```

I have tried these (and a few other variations on these) in both the external file and the head section within the HeaderLayout File.

I understand that C# runs before the page and the JavaScript mostly runs after the page (at least with events such as this).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Because I am plotting entries dynamically based off of a dynamic sql query.  Once done, they click on the entry they want and that entry is subsequently plotted on another "View & Edit" page, where they can look further into or update the entry.  Since I never know how many entries I am dealing with I need to read the unique ID of the field they select.  I suppose I could use a radio button and another input submit button and just post to the other page, but the current page already has one submit button. I've never used 2 submit buttons before, but I don't foresee a problem with it, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. You cannot set variables in the C#/Razor side with JavaScript without using a form post or ajax submit.

Javascript doesn't get access to the page until after Razor has done it's part and rendered and sent the page.

Comment: That makes sense, do I need to use another library or plugin (like jQuery) to use AJAX?  Or does it kind of work with jQuery?  What AJAX call could I use?

Comment: Another problem is that this form already submits and uses if(IsPost), could I just redirect to new page with a different input submit button?